# Array Doesn't load PNGs Exported from After Effects: ios, xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, image, after-effects

Our graphic designer is sending us .PNGs named appropiately "hide_00~iphone.png", "hide_00@2X~iphone.png" etc

He is exporting the images from after effects. I add them to the project and try to load them into an array on init. An exception is thrown each time for all of his files. Now, if I go in AND RENAME the files in the finder to exactly the same name, everything compiles fine. I have no idea what's going on here. Xcode cannot find them in the file system until I rename them. But the name is EXACTLY the same as what he sent me. I checked for white space around his file naming but everything looks fine.

Does anybody know if After Effects puts weird header info in the images? Or does this sound familiar at all to anyone. There are a whole bunch of images we are working with and I would hate to have to rename them by hand.

Comment: Can you put one of the images in a public DropBox folder, then attach the URL to that file? What you should do is get a file that fails, zip it, unzip it, and insure that it still does not work - then upload the .zip file (otherwise, if zip/unzip "fixes" the problem we cannot help.)

Comment: Yes, here is the public link: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/538153/hide_step_seq_06%7Eiphone.png One thing I forgot to mention is also very strange. The images load fine using imageWithName, but I am loading them with imageWithFileContents. So one array technique is OK, the other fails - that is unless I rename them

Comment: Look at the URL you just posted - its not a zip as I asked, but the iphone.png file is prefixed with a %7E - between 06 and phone.png.

Comment: Sorry about that https://dl.dropbox.com/u/538153/hide_step_seq.zip I tried zipping and unzipping the files, but that didn't help. I also tried a batch resave from within Photoshop. Thanks.

Comment: In your comment above, the zip unzip was not proposed as a 'fix' for the problem, but a test to insure that doing so did NOT fix the problem and thus make it impossible for others to test.

Comment: In case it is not obvious, this is a very poor way to get movie content into an iOS app. You are going to be using up all the app memory and lots of CPU time to decode lots of images as PNGs like this. A much better approach is to convert the PNG images to an animated format on the desktop first. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13850242/763355

Answer (score 2):

So I just used imageNamed and the image loaded just fine. So obviously your routine to load the image by path/name is flawed. You can post that and it can be evaluated - but this has nothing to do with 'After Effects'.

EDIT: For the record, my system is Lion Xcode 4.4.1 and my project set for iOS 5.1. I took your file from dropbox, and verified that in my project I CAN load the image as you are trying to do:

```
for (int i = 6; i < 7; i++) {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hide_step_seq_%02d", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path  ofType:@"png"]];
    NSLog(@"PATH %@ image=%@", path, image);
}
2012-09-13 07:15:23.241 Searcher[58114:f803] PATH hide_step_seq_06 image=<UIImage: 0x6a4cb30>
```

So, where to go from here? I've tried to help several people here who get burned by the @2x or ~iphone suffixes. For some reason a few people cannot ever seem to get this to work - all I can think of is there is some flag deep in the system that gets toggled and there is no way to untoggle it.

My suggestion is to try using the actual complete file name - try appending ~iphone and see if that works.

You can also in Terminal do a 'ls *.png | od -c' before changing the name and afterwards, to verify that absolutely the characters are the same.

The last thought I have on this is that files have many attributes: creation time, last access, last modiied, extended attributes, permissions, etc. It is possible (while unlikely) that for some reason one of these values blocks the system from attempting to use the ~iphone suffix.

I really wish I could help you further. If you want to put a simple little project together that does nothing more than tries to open a few images and it fails, zip the whole project up, put on dropbox, I'd be more than willing to run it on my system to try and duplicate the problem. You can also do as I did in the code above and verify that path looks good and the image is nil.

Comment: but you haven't read the post. the code doesn't change, the image naming does and then it loads fine. `code` NSMutableArray *seq = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        [seq addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hide_step_seq_%02d", i] ofType:@"png"]]];
    } `code`

Comment: additionally, (as mentioned above) it DOES load fine with imageNamed. That's the strange thing. It's imageWithContentsOfFile that doesn't load the image - until it's renamed. Can anyone re-create?

Comment: You are most welcome, and thanks for the thanks. The downside to 'imageNamed' is that those images get cached by the system, so I completely understand why you would want to load them as you are trying to. Please update your question if you ever find a way to get it to work.