# Objective-c & large animated images

Tags: objective-c, performance, uiimageview, uiimage

So far I am using UIImageView with array of UIImages that are displaying one after another.

Same linke in this example:

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"instruction_1"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"instruction_2"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"instruction_3"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"instruction_2"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"instruction_1"]
                     ,nil];

UIImageView *butta = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
butta.animationImages = myImages;
butta.animationDuration = 1;
butta.animationRepeatCount = 0;
butta.alpha = 0;
[butta startAnimating];
```

But the problem is that this solution works until images are small ... but in my case, most of them are same as device max resolution (over 2000 width and 1500 height for landscape retina ipad) ... and it has alpha channel (.png) ... that cause poor performance, especially over slower devices (even on iPad 3) ...

Do You know any good alternative? I tried .svg graphics, but it was even worst.

How can I optimize it?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Regards David

Comment: make the images into a video, include it in your app bundle, play it

Comment: How many images are you talking about? Hundreds, or just a hand full?

Comment: In your concrete example, at least the last entry of instruction_1 is redundant. Get rid of it. The way you do it would cause instruction_1 to appear twice the time period from its sencond appearance onwards. (instruction_1 follows instruction_1)

Comment: If the total amount of storage used by the array of UIImage objects is the issue then I would not use an animated array. In that event I would schedule an NSTimer (or use [self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay] to trigger the changes and load the next image. The array would only contain the image names and not the full UIImage object. Doing so you would leave it to the cocoa framework to free the space or utilize cache logic where appropriate.

Comment: video is not an option, bacause I have to manimuplate this animation sometimes (change some frames) and that's the trouble if I wonna do it fast.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [AVAnimator](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/) before with great success. I had a similar issue in which I had to make very large images into a movie. There's a bit of a learning curve with it, but I believe he has numerous examples, which I just adapted to my use.