# Gif using UIImage+animtedGif class

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Using this class I am trying to load a gif url into `UIImageView`.
The thing is , for some url's it takes 10 seconds to load, others 2 seconds.
I have tried almost anything, but still the process is too slow. 1 second would be good, but i had never succeed getting there.
I have also tried with UIWebview which had its own issues .

Here is the code :

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            let fileUrl = NSURL(string:"http://45.media.tumblr.com/6785bae27b8f888fe825f0ade95796a3/tumblr_noenkbeTSw1qjmwryo1_500.gif" )
            let gif = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL(fileUrl!)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                 self.player.image = gif
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with most of the GIF reading tools I have looked at is that they read all the data in at load time and that they allocate memory for all of the decoded frames and hold all that uncompressed data in memory at the same time. This will lead to runtime performance problems and it will crash your app and possibly your device on large/long gifs. On the issue of loading time, there is not all that much you can do since the data does need to be downloaded and read. You are also just assuming that the network cache is going to handle hitting the same GIF over and over without going to the network again, which may or may not work well for you. For a solution that addresses these issues, see [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850242/763355) or you can also take a look at the flipboard solution [here](http://engineering.flipboard.com/2014/05/animated-gif/).

Comment: Thanks, your first link does not really mean anything to me, the second I have already read, seems that Flipboard just wanted to show theory but I dont really know (I couldn't find anybody who does) what to do with it. Its strange, that to play such a simple file in iOS, is almost not possible. its just a series of images, loading movies is x10 faster and easier . I don't really get this Gif thing with Apple.

Comment: Loading animation data is a lot harder than it looks. There are all sorts of runtime performance and memory management issues and getting it right is about 10 times harder than just "doing something". I am not sure what you mean about the links, I provided you links to AVAnimator and FLAnimatedImage packages which implement difficult GIF89a loading details for iOS.

Comment: Yea , would go with the Flipboard solution, thank you .

Comment: even with the Flipboard solution, sometimes it takes 25 seconds to load a Gif. This is strange, because even an HD movie, 1080P, of 3/4 seconds, takes much less. I am sure, it has to do with Apple's iOS, its not normal, anyway you look at it, that in 2016 it takes to an Intel processor, 25 seconds to load such a simple media to the screen.

Comment: You could convert the gif to a h.264 encoded movie. That way it would play right away as opposed to being fully decoded at the start. The image is 500x500, so it is not small. You could also use another format that supports direct playing.