# Memory optimization ios app, On Pushing app to background minimizing the app runtime memroy size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

I am developing big iOS app. Here I am using lots of animations in each view controller, and due to that some times app crashes due to memory.

Issue is described Below

- Pushing View Controller, where on Tapping the button, start `UIImage` animation with 10 images. Which increase the app memory usage from 13MB to 53MB(Checking in "Debug Navigator" of Xcode 8.1 and iPhone 5 with iOS 10.1).
- When Poping the View Controller it is not decrease the memory size.

But if I send the app to background at the same moment then it dramatically decreasing the memory to 17MB.

Can you please guide me regarding this, how I need to handle this situation.

Note:
- Both Objects (ViewController and Image Object) calling its `dealloc` method, So means they should free the memory. 
- I even tried `@autorelease pool`, but not helpful.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You need to use a different approach that does not load all decoded image data into memory at the same time. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13850242/763355

Answer (score 0):

might be you didn't sop this animation, on viewWillDisappear try to call 
stopAnimating (in case you are using UIImageView for frame animation).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I already tried by stopping the animation and even on poping dealloc method of imageview is called, As I subclass the UIImageView class and wrinte nslog under dealloc method.

Here the main issue is that, the total size of images is 2MB approx, when when I load these images to assign the array to UIImageView the App size dramatically increased by 40MB. Can you please guide regarding this, that how I need to you the images in optimized way?